# How do I mark a group in polkit as administrator?

Tags: users, smb, policykit

I am using authentication via smb and want all users of the admins group as local administrators.

For this I created the `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/60-local.conf` file as described in `pklocalauthority(8)` man page containing

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin;unix-group:domain-admins;unix-group:admins
```

The file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf` provided by the package `policykit-1` contains

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin
```

and seems to work...

I checked that I am inside the group `admins` and `domain-admins` but whenever I want to do something requiring higher privileges I am getting asked for the password of the local (non-smb) administrator.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I have not had a chance to test this theory out but I quote these lines from the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pklocalauthority.8.html):

> The file 50-localauthority.conf contains the settings provided by the
>   OS vendor. Users and 3rd party packages can drop configuration files
>   with a priority higher than 60 to change the defaults.

I think all you had to do was change your file name to `61-local.conf` and that may have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a known issue.](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2904)

At this time it is unknown if this will be corrected, as the current behavior is to just select the first user.